# Routing traffic from a specific application

Tags: windows, networking, routes, packet, traffic

Is there a way I can route traffic from an application to a diferent ip, let's say for instance route Firefox's traffic to localhost, for instance?

I'm using windows.

Comment: Maybe [Putty](http://oldsite.precedence.co.uk/nc/putty.html) can help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a wide variety of [proxifer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_proxifiers), firewall and port forwarding software that allows you to redirect traffic by IP address, protocol, internal port, and external port through a range of different  packages for windows.

However, the only one I have found that allows you to specify rules (other than block) at the application level for Windows is the trialware package '[Proxifer](http://www.proxifier.com/)' by Initex software.

Comment: That list of proxifiers seems to be about application level proxying. It looks like they wrap traffic in proxy commands. I don't want to change any of the data inside the tcp session (which it looks like they do), I just want to change where the packets go.