# Routing call from localhost to external ip to locahost

Tags: networking, windows-7, routes

On localhost a program is calling an external IP in a specific port. I'm monitoring this via wireshark. Standard TCP connection.

What's the easiest way to route the traffic to the external IP back to localhost on a specific port?

Thanks

Comment: This isn't clear; generally speaking, a random [ephemeral port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port) is assigned by the TCP/IP stack.  Why do you need to assign a specific one?

Comment: It needs to be a specific port in order to listen to the data coming in and returning data to the program.

Possible solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067970/routing-traffic-from-a-specific-application?rq=1

Comment: Oh I see; you're saying you want to hijack outgoing traffic and redirect it straight back to something listening locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure your network card to have a second IP address - the external one.
When the IP packet gets routed, it turns out that it needs to be delivered locally.
If you listen locally to any address, you'll pick it up.
Alternatively you can listen locally to the specific IP address.